# How to make a face authetication login via web server in android?

Tags: android

is it possible to create a face authentication login via web server using android? If yes can you guide me how to do it? if it's not can you give an idea on how to accomplish that using mobile phone (android). I know it is much but I hope you can help me

Answer (score 0):

Android has the BiometricManager.Authenticators interface which allows you to create Security Authentication for your application. It have some override methods to detect errors, canceling, and failure but they  aren't supported on Android 10 (API level 29) and lower.

If you want to use it with Web Server, create an interface wich send information about the Validation or Failure of the Authentication so you can manage all that

See Android Documentation for more: https://developer.android.com/training/sign-in/biometric-auth